# pandas returning a dataframe instead of a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2 column dataframe that contains a date and a float value.  I have code that finds the minimum and maximum float value.  Then I want to retrieve the date value from the same row as the min and max, but instead of returning that date value (or string), the code is returning a 1 row, 1 column dataframe with the desired value.

```
    max_weight = weight[weight.columns[1]].astype(float).max()
    min_weight = weight[weight.columns[1]].astype(float).min()

    max_weight_date = weight['Date'][ weight[weight.columns[1]].astype(float) ==  max_weight].astype(str) 
    min_weight_date = weight['Date'][ weight[weight.columns[1]].astype(float) ==  min_weight ].astype(str)
```

I tried adding the `.astype(str)` hoping that might help but it made no difference. My hunch is that while there is currently only 1 value being returned, the code could theoretically return more than 1 row and hence the dataframe result.  How can I change this code to return just the value of the date column into a simple string/date as opposed to a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the value of the date column by using the .item() method on the resulting dataframe. This will return the scalar value of the dataframe, rather than a dataframe.

Try this:

```
max_weight = weight[weight.columns[1]].astype(float).max()
min_weight = weight[weight.columns[1]].astype(float).min()

max_weight_date = str(weight['Date'][ weight[weight.columns[1]].astype(float) ==  max_weight].item())
min_weight_date = str(weight['Date'][ weight[weight.columns[1]].astype(float) ==  min_weight ].item())
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly!  I was hoping it was something like this but i just didn't know what function to call to accomplish was I was looking for.